# How do I get the corresponding elements for a set of co-ordinates from an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position

I have a csv file containing co-ordinates. I want to know all the elements which were there at that co-ordinate. I know about the function :

```
 document.elementFromPoint(co-ordX,co-ordY)
```

which returns the element at the postion. One possible solution I know about is manually coping this into the HTML source. Is there a way to automate this (copying the script into the HTML source and then opening the HTML file in the browser) since I have a number of HTML files and this needs to be done for all of them?

Comment: `document.elementFromPoint` is not `jQuery` function, it's a native method of document object.

BTW, are you asking how to do script injection to someones website..? o.0

Comment: oops! corrected the error. No, So I have the data corresponding to eye tracker and therefore need the elements.

Comment: You cannot do that using js on external website (not same domain). You could reproxify it but...

Comment: I have saved these websites on my desktop and I'll be changing the HTML source locally.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be how do I add the same JS to a bunch of html files.

The simple solution is to put your code in a file called track.js and the use a decent code editor to do multi-file search and replace. I would suggest using sublime text 2 for this. Open the folder with you files and then replace

```
</head>
```

With

```
<script src="track.js"></script></head>
```